# repo tool manifest checkout a single file

Tags: manifest, repo

I am using manifest with repo.
I would like to take one part of the external repository, a sub folder or a file, is it possible?

assuming that I have

```
A/a_1/a_2/a_file.x
```

with

```
<project name="A" ..... />
```

I can take A, is it possible to take a_2 and/or a_file.x ?

Comment: name attribute in manifest file is the URL of git repository(combined with remote attribute), I do not think you can specify a sub folder or a file for it.

Comment: Maybe you can use ELEMENT copyfile as children of a project element to copy a sub folder or a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried copyfile but at the end I decided to user linkfile

```
<project name="A">
    <linkfile src="a_1/a_2/a_file.x"
              dest="B/a_file.x" />
</project>
```

Comment: Can "linkfile" link a folder ?